# Check value in MyBatis mapper

Tags: mybatis

I have a strange error in a MyBatis mapper where I can check if a parameter is null but I can't check the value of the same parameter;

Here is an excerpt from my mapper:

```
<parameterMap id="OUTOCriteria" type="Map">
    <parameter property="name"          javaType="String" />
    <parameter property="parentOU"      javaType="Long" />
    <parameter property="type"          javaType="Integer" />
    <parameter property="statusTypeCurrent" javaType="Integer" />
</parameterMap>
```

Then later I do this check:

```
<if test="parentOU != null">
    <if test="parentOU.compareTo(new Long(1))">
        AND OU_STRC_ID ${parentOU.operator.sql} #{parentOU.value}
    </if>
</if>
```

The first check doesn't throw any error, but the nested check gives me this error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: ### Error querying database. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression '!parentOU.compareTo(new Long(1))'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "compareTo" failed for object parentOUEQUAL1 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: compareTo(java.lang.Long)] ### The error may exist in com/clearstream/iam/query/sqlmaps/OU.xml ### The error may involve ou.iamouDefaultQuery ### The error occurred while executing a query ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression '!parentOU.compareTo(new Long(1))'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "compareTo" failed for object parentOUEQUAL1 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: compareTo(java.lang.Long)]
```

What would be the correct syntax to test the value of my Long parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<if test="parentOU != null and parentOU.longValue() == 1">
    AND OU_STRC_ID ${parentOU.operator.sql} #{parentOU.value}
</if>
```

Comment: I tried `<if test="parentOU.value == 1">` and it worked. The crazy thing is that it works ONLY if I explicitly use `#{parentOU.value}` in the statement. If I don't, then an error is thrown.

Comment: I think that is because Long object is more complicated, try to use int, or long primitive