# MyBatis xml update query using set tag throws org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException

Tags: mysql, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper, badsqlgrammarexception

Built update query in MyBatis xml but no luck to pass BadSqlGrammarException

Here's my query

```
    <update id="updateRecordingVideoStatus">
        UPDATE
            game_record_metadata
            <set>
                <if test="modifiedVideoStatus = null">
                        status = #{originalVideoStatus}
                </if>
                <if test="modifiedVideoStatus != null">
                        status = #{modifiedVideoStatus}
                </if>
            </set>
        WHERE id = #{gameRecordMetadataId}
        AND game_id = #{gameId}
    </update>
```

I've tried below(without set tag) but not working

```
                <if test="modifiedVideoStatus = null">
                       SET status = #{originalVideoStatus}
                </if>
                <if test="modifiedVideoStatus != null">
                       SET status = #{modifiedVideoStatus}
                </if>
```

EDIT

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 2
        AND game_id = 204' at line 5
### The error may exist in file [/Users/asd/admin-api/build/resources/main/mybatis/rel/game_recording.xml]
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE             game_record_metadata                                     WHERE id = ?         AND game_id = ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 2
        AND game_id = 204' at line 5
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 2
        AND game_id = 204' at line 5
```

What would be the correct one for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace of an exception?

Comment: @Maksim Eliseev 
Updated. 
Not too sure tough, it does not seem like 
executing 'set status = originalVideoStatus or modifiedVideoStatus' as the trace showing

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both `<if>` statements are not selected. That is, both conditions in the `test="..."` are false. And the query beacame incorrect:

```
UPDATE game_record_metadata
 WHERE id = #{gameRecordMetadataId}
   AND game_id = #{gameId}
```

It happened because you use unexistied table columns in the `test`:

- `test="modifiedVideoStatus = null"`
- `test="modifiedVideoStatus != null"`

You should use the column names in the `test` condition first rather than passed parameters. Fortunately, there are solutions to this problem, but I am not sure that will work:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12663093/22270964
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226272/22270964

They look confusing and non-obvious.

---

I suggest you check the `originalVideoStatus` and `modifiedVideoStatus` parameters in the code and use the one general query to update the `game_record_metadata.status` column.

```xml
<update id="updateGameRecordMetadataStatus">
    UPDATE game_record_metadata
       SET status = #{newStatus}
     WHERE id = #{gameRecordMetadataId}
       AND game_id = #{gameId}
</update>
```

Comment: You can actually use parameters  fot if tag <if test: "parameter can be here"> from mapper class

Answer (score 1):

<s>Somehow, `test:` in if tag does not work with null but not null and it's ignored then caused BadSqlGrammarException as SET statements do not exist in that update query.</s>

```
<if test="modifiedVideoStatus = null"> /* assignment(NG) */
     status = #{originalVideoStatus}
</if>
```

So I passed a Boolean parameter as flag so that it can catch firt if.

```
-- solved
 <set>
            <if test="isModifiedVideoStatusNull">
                status = #{originalVideoStatus}
            </if>
            <if test="!isModifiedVideoStatusNull">
                status = #{modifiedVideoStatus}
            </if>
        </set>
```

As ave mentioned

```
EDIT

<if test="modifiedVideoStatus = null"> /* incorrect */      
     status = #{originalVideoStatus}
</if>

<if test="modifiedVideoStatus == null"> /* correct */      
     status = #{originalVideoStatus}
</if>
```

Comment: Well, ` <if test="modifiedVideoStatus = null">` is an assignment. It should be ` <if test="modifiedVideoStatus == null">`.

Comment: @ave I am shocked, thank you!

Comment: @MaksimEliseev You're welcome :) As this mistake does not throw exception, it could be a little bit tricky, I guess.